# when I use .pivot() on pyspark it returns some lines before the output

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the df below

```
+---+---+---+---------+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|      _c3|
+---+---+---+---------+
|196|242|  3|881250949|
|186|302|  3|891717742|
| 22|377|  1|878887116|
|244| 51|  2|880606923|
|166|346|  1|886397596|
+---+---+---+---------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

When I try to pivot I get a weird output

```
df.groupBy("_c0").pivot("_c1").sum("_c1").show()
```

```
----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|_c0|   1|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|   7|   8|   9|  10|  11|  12|  13|  14|  15|  16|  17|  18|  19|  20|  21|  22|  23|  24|  25|  26|  27|  28|  29|  30|  31|  32|  33|  34|  35|  36|  37|  38|  39|  40|  41|  42|  43|  44|  45|  46|  47|  48|  49|  50|  51|  52|  53|  54|  55|  56|  57|  58|  59|  60|  61|  62|  63|  64|  65|  66|  67|  68|  69|  70|  71|  72|  73|  74|  75|  76|  77|  78|  79|  80|  81|  82|  83|  84|  85|  86|  87|  88|  89|  90|  91|  92|  93|  94|  95|  96|  97|  98|  99| 100| 101| 102| 103| 104| 105| 106| 107| 108| 109| 110| 111| 112| 113| 114| 115| 116| 117| 118| 119| 120| 121| 122| 123| 124| 125| 126| 127| 128| 129| 130| 131| 132| 133| 134| 135| 136| 137| 138| 139| 140| 141| 142| 143| 144| 145| 146| 147| 148| 149| 150| 151| 152| 153| 154| 155| 156| 157| 158| 159| 160| 161| 162| 163| 164| 165| 166| 167| 168| 169| 170| 171| 172| 173| 174| 175| 176| 177| 178| 179| 180| 181| 182| 183| 184| 185| 186| 187| 188| 189| 190| 191| 192| 193| 194| 195| 196| 197| 198| 199| 200| 201| 202| 203| 204| 205| 206| 207| 208| 209| 210| 211| 212| 213| 214| 215| 216| 217| 218| 219| 220| 221| 222| 223| 224| 225| 226| 227| 228| 229| 230| 231| 232| 233| 234| 235| 236| 237| 238| 239| 240| 241| 242| 243| 244| 245| 246| 247| 248| 249| 250| 251| 252| 253| 254| 255| 256| 257| 258| 259| 260| 261| 262| 263| 264| 265| 266| 267| 268| 269| 270| 271| 272| 273| 274| 275| 276| 277| 278| 279| 280| 281| 282| 283| 284| 285| 286| 287| 288| 289| 290| 291| 292| 293| 294| 295| 296| 297| 298| 299| 300| 301| 302| 303| 304| 305| 306| 307| 308| 309| 310| 311| 312| 313| 314| 315| 316| 317| 318| 319| 320| 321| 322| 323| 324| 325| 326| 327| 328| 329| 330| 331| 332| 333| 334| 335| 336| 337| 338| 339| 340| 341| 342| 343| 344| 345| 346| 347| 348| 349| 350| 351| 352| 353| 354| 355| 356| 357| 358| 359| 360| 361| 362| 363| 364| 365| 366| 367| 368| 369| 370| 371| 372| 373| 374| 375| 376| 377| 378| 379| 380| 381| 382| 383| 384| 385| 386| 387| 388| 389| 390| 391| 392| 393| 394| 395| 396| 397| 398| 399| 400| 401| 402| 403| 404| 405| 406| 407| 408| 409| 410| 411| 412| 413| 414| 415| 416| 417| 418| 419| 420| 421| 422| 423| 424| 425| 426| 427| 428| 429| 430| 431| 432| 433| 434| 435| 436| 437| 438| 439| 440| 441| 442| 443| 444| 445| 446| 447| 448| 449| 450| 451| 452| 453| 454| 455| 456| 457| 458| 459| 460| 461| 462| 463| 464| 465| 466| 467| 468| 469| 470| 471| 472| 473| 474| 475| 476| 477| 478| 479| 480| 481| 482| 483| 484| 485| 486| 487| 488| 489| 490| 491| 492| 493| 494| 495| 496| 497| 498| 499| 500| 501| 502| 503| 504| 505| 506| 507| 508| 509| 510| 511| 512| 513| 514| 515| 516| 517| 518| 519| 520| 521| 522| 523| 524| 525| 526| 527| 528| 529| 530| 531| 532| 533| 534| 535| 536| 537| 538| 539| 540| 541| 542| 543| 544| 545| 546| 547| 548| 549| 550| 551| 552| 553| 554| 555| 556| 557| 558| 559| 560| 561| 562| 563| 564| 565| 566| 567| 568| 569| 570| 571| 572| 573| 574| 575| 576| 577| 578| 579| 580| 581| 582| 583| 584| 585| 586| 587| 588| 589| 590| 591| 592| 593| 594| 595| 596| 597| 598| 599| 600| 601| 602| 603| 604| 605| 606| 607| 608| 609| 610| 611| 612| 613| 614| 615| 616| 617| 618| 619| 620| 621| 622| 623| 624| 625| 626| 627| 628| 629| 630| 631| 632| 633| 634| 635| 636| 637| 638| 639| 640| 641| 642| 643| 644| 645| 646| 647| 648| 649| 650| 651| 652| 653| 654| 655| 656| 657| 658| 659| 660| 661| 662| 663| 664| 665| 666| 667| 668| 669| 670| 671| 672| 673| 674| 675| 676| 677| 678| 679| 680| 681| 682| 683| 684| 685| 686| 687| 688| 689| 690| 691| 692| 693| 694| 695| 696| 697| 698| 699| 700| 701| 702| 703| 704| 705| 706| 707| 708| 709| 710| 711| 712| 713| 714| 715| 716| 717| 718| 719| 720| 721| 722| 723| 724| 725| 726| 727| 728| 729| 730| 731| 732| 733| 734| 735| 736| 737| 738| 739| 740| 741| 742| 743| 744| 745| 746| 747| 748| 749| 750| 751| 752| 753| 754| 755| 756| 757| 758| 759| 760| 761| 762| 763| 764| 765| 766| 767| 768| 769| 770| 771| 772| 773| 774| 775| 776| 777| 778| 779| 780| 781| 782| 783| 784| 785| 786| 787| 788| 789| 790| 791| 792| 793| 794| 795| 796| 797| 798| 799| 800| 801| 802| 803| 804| 805| 806| 807| 808| 809| 810| 811| 812| 813| 814| 815| 816| 817| 818| 819| 820| 821| 822| 823| 824| 825| 826| 827| 828| 829| 830| 831| 832| 833| 834| 835| 836| 837| 838| 839| 840| 841| 842| 843| 844| 845| 846| 847| 848| 849| 850| 851| 852| 853| 854| 855| 856| 857| 858| 859| 860| 861| 862| 863| 864| 865| 866| 867| 868| 869| 870| 871| 872| 873| 874| 875| 876| 877| 878| 879| 880| 881| 882| 883| 884| 885| 886| 887| 888| 889| 890| 891| 892| 893| 894| 895| 896| 897| 898| 899| 900| 901| 902| 903| 904| 905| 906| 907| 908| 909| 910| 911| 912| 913| 914| 915| 916| 917| 918| 919| 920| 921| 922| 923| 924| 925| 926| 927| 928| 929| 930| 931| 932| 933| 934| 935| 936| 937| 938| 939| 940| 941| 942| 943| 944| 945| 946| 947| 948| 949| 950| 951| 952| 953| 954| 955| 956| 957| 958| 959| 960| 961| 962| 963| 964| 965| 966| 967| 968| 969| 970| 971| 972| 973| 974| 975| 976| 977| 978| 979| 980| 981| 982| 983| 984| 985| 986| 987| 988| 989| 990| 991| 992| 993| 994| 995| 996| 997| 998| 999|1000|1001|1002|1003|1004|1005|1006|1007|1008|1009|1010|1011|1012|1013|1014|1015|1016|1017|1018|1019|1020|1021|1022|1023|1024|1025|1026|1027|1028|1029|1030|1031|1032|1033|1034|1035|1036|1037|1038|1039|1040|1041|1042|1043|1044|1045|1046|1047|1048|1049|1050|1051|1052|1053|1054|1055|1056|1057|1058|1059|1060|1061|1062|1063|1064|1065|1066|1067|1068|1069|1070|1071|1072|1073|1074|1075|1076|1077|1078|1079|1080|1081|1082|1083|1084|1085|1086|1087|1088|1089|1090|1091|1092|1093|1094|1095|1096|1097|1098|1099|1100|1101|1102|1103|1104|1105|1106|1107|1108|1109|1110|1111|1112|1113|1114|1115|1116|1117|1118|1119|1120|1121|1122|1123|1124|1125|1126|1127|1128|1129|1130|1131|1132|1133|1134|1135|1136|1137|1138|1139|1140|1141|1142|1143|1144|1145|1146|1147|1148|1149|1150|1151|1152|1153|1154|1155|1156|1157|1158|1159|1160|1161|1162|1163|1164|1165|1166|1167|1168|1169|1170|1171|1172|1173|1174|1175|1176|1177|1178|1179|1180|1181|1182|1183|1184|1185|1186|1187|1188|1189|1190|1191|1192|1193|1194|1195|1196|1197|1198|1199|1200|1201|1202|1203|1204|1205|1206|1207|1208|1209|1210|1211|1212|1213|1214|1215|1216|1217|1218|1219|1220|1221|1222|1223|1224|1225|1226|1227|1228|1229|1230|1231|1232|1233|1234|1235|1236|1237|1238|1239|1240|1241|1242|1243|1244|1245|1246|1247|1248|1249|1250|1251|1252|1253|1254|1255|1256|1257|1258|1259|1260|1261|1262|1263|1264|1265|1266|1267|1268|1269|1270|1271|1272|1273|1274|1275|1276|1277|1278|1279|1280|1281|1282|1283|1284|1285|1286|1287|1288|1289|1290|1291|1292|1293|1294|1295|1296|1297|1298|1299|1300|1301|1302|1303|1304|1305|1306|1307|1308|1309|1310|1311|1312|1313|1314|1315|1316|1317|1318|1319|1320|1321|1322|1323|1324|1325|1326|1327|1328|1329|1330|1331|1332|1333|1334|1335|1336|1337|1338|1339|1340|1341|1342|1343|1344|1345|1346|1347|1348|1349|1350|1351|1352|1353|1354|1355|1356|1357|1358|1359|1360|1361|1362|1363|1364|1365|1366|1367|1368|1369|1370|1371|1372|1373|1374|1375|1376|1377|1378|1379|1380|1381|1382|1383|1384|1385|1386|1387|1388|1389|1390|1391|1392|1393|1394|1395|1396|1397|1398|1399|1400|1401|1402|1403|1404|1405|1406|1407|1408|1409|1410|1411|1412|1413|1414|1415|1416|1417|1418|1419|1420|1421|1422|1423|1424|1425|1426|1427|1428|1429|1430|1431|1432|1433|1434|1435|1436|1437|1438|1439|1440|1441|1442|1443|1444|1445|1446|1447|1448|1449|1450|1451|1452|1453|1454|1455|1456|1457|1458|1459|1460|1461|1462|1463|1464|1465|1466|1467|1468|1469|1470|1471|1472|1473|1474|1475|1476|1477|1478|1479|1480|1481|1482|1483|1484|1485|1486|1487|1488|1489|1490|1491|1492|1493|1494|1495|1496|1497|1498|1499|1500|1501|1502|1503|1504|1505|1506|1507|1508|1509|1510|1511|1512|1513|1514|1515|1516|1517|1518|1519|1520|1521|1522|1523|1524|1525|1526|1527|1528|1529|1530|1531|1532|1533|1534|1535|1536|1537|1538|1539|1540|1541|1542|1543|1544|1545|1546|1547|1548|1549|1550|1551|1552|1553|1554|1555|1556|1557|1558|1559|1560|1561|1562|1563|1564|1565|1566|1567|1568|1569|1570|1571|1572|1573|1574|1575|1576|1577|1578|1579|1580|1581|1582|1583|1584|1585|1586|1587|1588|1589|1590|1591|1592|1593|1594|1595|1596|1597|1598|1599|1600|1601|1602|1603|1604|1605|1606|1607|1608|1609|1610|1611|1612|1613|1614|1615|1616|1617|1618|1619|1620|1621|1622|1623|1624|1625|1626|1627|1628|1629|1630|1631|1632|1633|1634|1635|1636|1637|1638|1639|1640|1641|1642|1643|1644|1645|1646|1647|1648|1649|1650|1651|1652|1653|1654|1655|1656|1657|1658|1659|1660|1661|1662|1663|1664|1665|1666|1667|1668|1669|1670|1671|1672|1673|1674|1675|1676|1677|1678|1679|1680|1681|1682|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|463|   1|null|   3|null|null|null|   7|null|null|  10|null|null|  13|  14|  15|  16|null|null|  19|  20|  21|null|null|  24|  25|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|  50|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|  93|null|null|null|null|null|null| 100|null|null| 103|null|null|null| 107|null|null|null| 111| 112|null|null|null| 116| 117|null|null|null| 121|null|null| 124| 125| 126| 127|null| 129|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 137|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 147|null| 149| 150| 151|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 221|null|null| 224| 225|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 235|null| 237|null|null|null|null| 242| 243| 244|null| 246|null| 248| 249| 250|null|null| 253|null|null|null| 257| 258|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 268| 269| 270| 271|null|null| 274| 275| 276|null|null|null|null|null| 282| 283| 284| 285| 286|null| 288|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 301| 302|null| 304|null| 306|null|null|null| 310| 311|null| 313|null|null|null|null|null| 319|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 347|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 362|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 410|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 455|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 472| 473|null| 475| 476| 477|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 508|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 539|null|null|null|null| 544|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 591|null| 593|null|null| 596| 597|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 689| 690|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 740| 741|null|null| 744|null|null|null|null| 749|null| 751|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 764|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 813|null|null|null|null|null| 819|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 845|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 864|null| 866|null|null|null| 870|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 880|null|null|null|null|null|null| 887|null|null|null|null| 892|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 926|null|null|null| 930|null|null|null|null|null| 936|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 950|null| 952|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null| 985|null|null| 988|null|null|null|null| 993|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|1007|null|1009|null|null|1012|null|1014|null|null|1017|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|1028|null|null|null|null|1033|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|nu
```

I was expecting something like this

```
+---+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|_c0|sum(_c0)|sum(_c1)|sum(_c2)|    sum(_c3)|
+---+--------+--------+--------+------------+
|148|    9620|   20477|     260| 57015708303|
|463|   61579|   68520|     381|117330476410|
|471|   14601|   12745|     105| 27584665871|
|496|   63984|   55859|     391|113012720997|
|833|  222411|  120157|     816|233864911856|
+---+--------+--------+--------+------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

but with only the "_c1" column

-But if I run

```
df.groupBy("_c0").sum("_c1").show()
```

It works perfectly

```
+---+--------+
|_c0|sum(_c1)|
+---+--------+
|148|   20477|
|463|   68520|
|471|   12745|
|496|   55859|
|833|  120157|
|243|   32869|
|392|   44650|
|540|   23091|
|623|   13677|
|737|    6210|
|858|    8495|
|897|   70342|
| 31|   16499|
|516|    7532|
|251|   26358|
| 85|  128105|
|137|   16132|
|451|   60179|
|580|   16638|
|808|    9406|
+---+--------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I just want to know why it doesn't work with the first code using `.pivot()`

Comment: your expected output does not require a pivot, instead it is a simple `groupBy().agg(<multiple column aggs>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't use pivot in that case.

> The PIVOT clause is used for data perspective. We can get the aggregated values based on specific column values, which will be turned to multiple columns.

Ex:

| c0 | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banana | 15 |
| 2 | orange | 20 |

After execution of

```
df.groupBy("_c0").pivot("_c1").sum("_c2").show()
```

| c0 | banana | orange |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | null |
| 2 | null | 20 |